# Send date and retrieve information using PHP and AJAX in form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, xmlhttprequest

I'm novice in AJAX and PHP programming.
I believe this is quite simple, but I'm with difficult.

What I need is that user select a date (using jquery date picker) and click in OK button.

The form will call page query.php (via Ajax). The query.php will check the date.
If the date have registries in the database, query.php will return a table populated for index.php.

I have based my script according this example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

But in that example, the trigger is the event ( onchange="showUser(this.value)"). 
I need to call AJAX function after submit the form.

I did that using (), but when I try to get the date using $q = $_GET['q']; the value come as blank.

Index.php (relevant information):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='pt-BR'>
<head>
    <script>
    function showUser(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","checar_data.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="dateForm" onsubmit="showUser(); return false;" method="GET">
        Data:
        <input name="datepicker" id="datepicker" type="text" size="10" maxlength="8" />
        <input name="OK" value="OK" type="submit" >
    </form>        
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

query.php:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

echo "$q -> bla bla";


?>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query.php

change to

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];
echo "$q";
?>
```

send data page is not correct

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","checar_data.php?q="+str,true);
```

change to

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","query.php?q="+str,true);
```

your function have one parameter and leave empty
form declare at startup,

change from

```
<form id="dateForm" onsubmit="showUser(); return false;" method="GET">
```

to

```
<form id="dateForm" onsubmit="showUser(this.datepicker.value); return false;" method="GET">
```

Comment: I correct the form submit method and works very well. Why the old way didn't work? tks

Comment: i don't know what is the old way :). i'm novice too, but 'showUser()' have one parameter which send to query.php page and in old code you send nothing to this parameter.

Comment: Ah now I understand showUser(this.datepicker.value), I need to specific which field  will send data to query.php. Tks a lot man :)